# How to set up Mac Os X like dragging behaviour on Linux

Tags: linux, mac, macbook-pro, touchpad

I would like to use Linux(Fedora) on a Aluminum MacBook Pro, but since the Touchpad on a MacBook Pro is only a giant button Apple does some custom tracking.

- When there is one finger placed, and a second follows (the click can occur before or after that) it will be interpreted as a drag. So the strong thumb can be used to hold pressure and the more accurate index finger can do the pointing.
- Additionally when one finger is in the lower 1/5 and the other is in the upper 4/5 the gesture will be a drag.

But Linux interprets this as a right click, since it only cares if two fingers are on the pad.

Is there a way to achieve said behaviour?

Cheers Jan

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with scrolling, does it?

Comment: Um...finger placement doesn't really matter on a trackpad in OS X. You can use 3 and 4 finger gestures from any points on the pad. 3 finger gestures is configurable to be a drag, but by default its not enabled.

Comment: true it is timing, don't know why it felt otherwise before

Comment: Does that mean your question is answered? Care to add that as a solution and mark it as such?